# How to make user must allow certain permission to continue using apps

Tags: android, permissions

I am developing an apps where permission to write internal storage is crucial. When I am requesting permission for api >23, there is an option to never show the request permission dialog again. I wanted to disable this because if the user choose to deny and check never show the request dialog again, then the user will have to personally go to settings and clear the apps reference himself, which I want to avoid. I also want to keep requesting for permission if the user choose deny, but resulting in error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in grantResults[0].

To summarize my problem:
1. how to disable the "never show again check"
2. my error's fix

here's my code in requesting permission again if the user choose deny:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Update();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I don't believe this to be impossible, there is a reason that the android developers have implemented the lock down on the external storage as well as the "never ask again" feature on the permissions. It is likely that without finding some hackish way to work around it, you wont have a resolution to this problem. It may be worth considering why you are having this problem and seeing if there is a way to accomplish what you would like, without trying to go against how android functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop the user from permanently denying the permission. When the user does an action that requires the permission, and the permission is denied, you can flash a message - a Toast or a Snackbar, for example.

Answer (score 1):

try this my friend

```
 String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
    }



@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
    @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this, "permission  granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but after analyzing my problem i found that it is better to show dialog as to why the permission are needed instead as answered above.